# Forward any request to another server on specific port

Tags: port-forwarding

Let's assume 3 servers.

Server A streams live video on port 88.
Server B fetches 10 live streams from Server A. Connection speed between Server A -> Server B is 20mbps.

Server C can connect to Server A at 100mbps via internal routing.
Connection between Server C and B is also about 20mbps. It doesn't interfere with ServerA<>ServerB connection.

Question: Is it possible to fetch another 10 streams(20mbps needed) from Server A to Server B while using Server C's connection. What needs to be done on Server C? Tunneling?

On server B: Current config

ingest {Server A IP}:88/stream{stream01-10}

If what I am trying to do is possible final config will be like this on Server B

```
fetch {Server A IP}:88/stream{stream01-10}
fetch {Server C IP}:88/stream{stream11-20}
```

[Diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtzi.png)

Answer (score 1):

If a single client initiated TCP connection on a known port is sufficient You could use iptables to forward the connection from server C to server B with dnat+snat.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate? I'm note good with iptables.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [eohm](https://serverfault.com/users/543402/eohm) I figured it out.

Here is what I did on Server C.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 88 -j DNAT --to-destination SERVERA-IP:88
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d SERVERAIP --dport 88 -j SNAT --to-source SERVERC-IP
```

Comment: Exactly something like that. Fine that You figured it out even thought I had typo in my answer.